# Using SQL Server triggers to impose constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I understand the idea of triggers but a bit confused on how to use it to impose constraints. For example I have two tables: a `student` table and a `book_order` table that shows what book a student orders.

I want to create a trigger that will check that a student with a book order cannot be deleted from the student table.

Comment: As an alternative, you should use a foreign key constraint on the `book_order` table, referencing the `student` table, as I don't think you need a trigger for this scenario.

Comment: The question is WHY use a trigger instead of a foeign key?

Comment: A foreign key constraint is not merely an "alternative".  It is the right way to express this condition.  You should not use triggers for this.  You should not be learning to use triggers for this.

Comment: I was asked to use triggers to solve this problem

Comment: @jasmine That's not a good thing, it's like being asked to beat a nail with a screwdriver. You can, but you'd end up using the wrong part of the screwdriver (the handle) to beat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would ever do this unless you wanted to write to a log or something when it happened but.....

```
create TRIGGER Del_Student
ON dbo.Student
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
   Declare @cnt int
   Select @cnt = count(*) from deleted d 
     Inner Join BookOrders o on d.studentId = o.studentId
   if (@cnt > 0)
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('Deletions not allowed from this table when bookorders exist for student)',     16, 1)
   END  
END
```

Comment: thank you. I'm getting errors saying: Create trigger must be the only statement in batch, incorrect syntax near '@declare' and incorrect syntax near (the last) End

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!